# NextUI + Next.js 14.0.3 Collision: TypeError When Using nextui() Plugin

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, typeerror, postcss, nextui

Fellow Next.js and NextUI enthusiasts, I'm encountering a perplexing error that's halting my development journey. I'm seeking your collective wisdom to guide me through this impasse.

Here's the scenario:

**Next.js version:** 14.0.3
**NextUI version:** 2.2.9
**Tailwind CSS version:** 3.3.3

The challenge:

Upon integrating the **nextui()** plugin into my Tailwind configuration, I'm confronted with this error:
./src/app/globals.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[12].oneOf[12].use[3]!./src/app/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase').

Here's my Tailwind configuration:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
import { nextui } from "@nextui-org/react"

const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors")
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    darkMode: "class",
    content: [
        "./index.html",
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
        "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
        "./public/**/*.html",
        "./node_modules/flowbite-react/**/*.js",
        "./node_modules/flowbite-react/lib/esm/**/*.js",
        "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            primary: colors.indigo,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
        require("@tailwindcss/typography"),
        require("@tailwindcss/container-queries"),
        require("flowbite/plugin"),
        nextui(),
    ],
    future: {
        hoverOnlyWhenSupported: true,
    },
}
```

My `globals.css` file:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* ! Other CSS styling for customised components. */
```

---

I've attempted the following:

1. Reinstalling NextUI in case of any installation errors, ended up witht the same issue.
2. Removed the nextui() plugin for the tailwind.config.js file, the issue disappeared, but with no syling for NextUI components when used in the app.

---

I'm seeking guidance on:

- Identifying the root cause of this error.
- Rectifying the configuration to achieve harmonious coexistence between Next.js 14.0.3 and NextUI.
- Unveiling any potential compatibility issues or known workarounds.

**Solution:** Upgrading Node.js to the latest version rectified the problem. It appears the underlying issue was tied to a bug present in Node 21, which impacted the compatibility with NextUI when integrated into a Next.js project using Tailwind CSS.

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade the NextJS version to 13.x?

Comment: @adampweb Not really,  but I think the problem of this issue only occurs with Next 14, once downgraded it would fix the problem.

Comment: @adampweb Just downgraded to Next.js 13.5.5, problem persists with the typeerror. `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')`.

Comment: I tried a freshly installed NextJS 14 with Tailwind CSS and the latest version of NextUI. However, I have not experienced any errors. Note: I have not tried combining with Flowbite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact error -- the answer is to update your node version! [There is a bug in Node 21](https://www.framer.community/c/bugs/node-21-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-tolowercase). It has been fixed in the latest version:

> the issue is fixed with 21.1.0

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction! Funny thing, I had actually upgraded my Node version to v21.6.0 a few weeks back, not directly to address this issue but for other reasons. It didn't click until you mentioned it, but this upgrade must have inadvertently resolved the problem I was having with NextUI.

It all makes sense now, and everything, including Framer Motion, is working perfectly. Your advice was spot on, and I appreciate your help. It's amazing how sometimes these things get fixed in ways we don't immediately realize. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the NextJS version to 14.0.4 It worked for me.